# Receiving in app SMS messages only from certain specified numbers

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I've recently set up an app that will receive sms messages and then display them as a toast on the main activity. Once the app has received an SMS it will abort broadcast and stop the message from going into the inbox.

Currently it does this with all messages that the phone receives but I would like it to only carry out its job and display the toast when an SMS is received by a specific number. I know that it is a case of putting an if statement into my receiver code but I'm not too sure where abouts the it should be placed.

SmsReceiver.java:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


    if (extras ==null)
        return;
    //toast
    Toast.makeText(context, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();

        Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra("get_msg", sender+":"+body);

        context.sendBroadcast(in);
        this.abortBroadcast();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
String body=....
if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare(sender, phoneNumber)) {

            abortBroadcast() then do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put bellow

```
    String body=....
    if(sender.equals(phoneNumber)) {

                abortBroadcast() then do something...
    }
```

Be sure to do abortBroadcast as soon as possible, since if you do to many operations before it, the original inbox will pick up the message.

Comment: ah yes these seems to work perfect, thanks. Say I wanted the number to come from a variable, for example if I had the number stored as a string variable, how would I do that?

Comment: the variable i wrote "phoneNumber" is type String so it would be the same ;) . SMessage.getOriginatingAddress() returns the number in string format.

Comment: But keep in mind the prefix for the phone number. If i recall correctly the phone always returns the number with +44... or what ever is the area code is. So you must write the phone number in the same format or do some String operations to compare different formats.

Comment: yeah thanks for your help, I did find it was the case as you said, it will always read the number as it is e.g. +44.... what i have now done is used `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(sender, phoneNumber)`that way it allows the number to be read as an 07... number rather than +44...

Comment: I understood what you said ;) . Heh i actually forgot about PhoneNumberUtils and wrote my own parser for the area codes :D . Good thing you reminded me.

Answer (score 1):

```
if("123456789".equals(sender))
{
 //do something
}
```